# Arcore for Xiaomi mi 9

Tags: arcore, xiaomi

Will arcore work on Xiaomi mi 9?

Answer (score 0):

As of now Xiaomi mi 9 hasn't been included in the official list of [ArCore supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices).

There are people who state that they have been able to use ArCore on Mi 9 by installing the MIUI EU ROM. It enables the camera2 api setting which seems to have stopped ARCore apps from crashing when using ARCore. 
You'll have to sideload the ARCore app after installing EU ROM.

But **I would probably advice you against doing something like that**, since the 'guides' I've been able to find for doing so require you to root the device. It's probably not worth voiding your warranty for that. But if you insist on doing so, here's a [guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/Mi-9/how-to/guide-how-flashed-twrp-xiaomi-eu-rom-t3912952) I happened to find on the XDA-Developers forum.